# System call reading from file straight to stack, nasm

Tags: nasm, cpu-architecture

I am trying to write a PIC code in NASM 32 bit.
For that, I need to read from a file an amount of 4 bytes and check if it is an ELF file.
I did this:

eax has the file descriptor, so I did `push eax`, and checked that it is not -1, all is good.
But now, I want to use the read, to read 4 bytes, but since I need it as a PIC code, I must read straight into stack as a local variable. I did this (using macro system calls): `read [ebp-4 (fd)], [ebp-8] (to this place in stack), 4 (4 bytes)` However, returned value is `-14` as in it did not read anything.

I made a data section with a buffer, did the same but read into the buffer and it worked.

So, apparently, I can not read straight TO stack. How would I do this to maintain PIC code?

```
open Filename, RDWR, 0777
push eax ;backup fd, now its at place [ebp-4]
cmp eax, -1 ;if not a good fd
je exit
mov eax, 3 ;sys read
mov ebx, [ebp-4]
mov ecx, [ebp-8]
mov edx, 4
int 0x80
```

Comment: _"So, apparently, I can not read straight TO stack."_ That doesn't seem like the right conclusion to draw. More likely it's just something about how you're doing it that's preventing it from working. It would help if you posted the exact code you're using in both cases.

Comment: Added the problematic part.

Comment: Wouldn't you want `lea ecx,[ebp-8]`? Or do you have a pointer stored at `[ebp-8]`?

Comment: No I have no pointer at `[ebp-8]`

Comment: I did `lea` now and it works.
Thank you.